# continuously push accurate location to remote server

Tags: iphone, shortcut, geolocation, shortcuts-app

for reasons i want to push the accurate location of my iphone to a remote server. I want to automatically repeat this action every 10 Seconds for 4 hours. I have tried using the shortcuts app but it does not request the permission to access my location in the background. What other options do i have? I have found a „SendLocation“ App in the AppStore but it says that it only updates its location once there is some major movement. That does not fit my usecase.

Comment: Would https://github.com/fjxmlzn/FindMyHistory help?

Comment: thanks for the comment but unfortunately the find my history is to infrequent and slow for my usecase.